# How to print DataFrame on single line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('pima-data.csv')
print df.head(2)
```

the print is automatically formatted across multiple lines:

```
   num_preg  glucose_conc  diastolic_bp  thickness  insulin   bmi  diab_pred  \
0         6           148            72         35        0  33.6      0.627   
1         1            85            66         29        0  26.6      0.351   

   age    skin diabetes  
0   50  1.3790     True  
1   31  1.1426    False
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid the multi-line formatting. I would rather have it printed in a single line like so:

```
   num_preg  glucose_conc  diastolic_bp  thickness  insulin       bmi      diab_pred     age       skin      diabetes  
0         6           148            72         35        0      33.6          0.627      50     1.3790          True  
1         1            85            66         29        0      26.6          0.351      31     1.1426         False
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need set:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

`option_context` context manager has been exposed through the top-level API, allowing you to execute code with given option values. Option values are restored automatically when you exit the with block:

```
#temporaly set expand_frame_repr
with pd.option_context('expand_frame_repr', False):
    print (df)
```

[Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options).

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Spyder. I wonder if I should change some settings on Spyder, when I try this pd.set_option there is nor scroll bar so it becomes kind of a mess. Any suggestions for Spyder?

Comment: @JoeR - I check settings in `IPython` console and only you can change `Size` of font, but I dont find options for changing this. If check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment) it seems you can use only `set_option`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've been trying to make this work on Spyder for about a week but no luck. I tried all set_option variations but the result is always the same. Thanks again for your reply. I appreciate it.