# Displaying columns from csv to pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I've managed to display the columns from the csv to pandas on Python 3. However, the columns are being separated to 3 lines. Is it possible to squeeze all the columns onto a single line? This was done on jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = pd.read_csv("D:/Python/vitamin.csv")
print(raw.head())
```

**Result**

```
 RowID Gender   BMI  Energy_Actual  VitaminA_Actual  VitaminC_Actual  \
 0      1      F  18.0           1330              206               15   
 1      2      F  25.0           1792              469               59   
 2      3      F  21.6           1211              317               18   
 3      4      F  23.9           1072              654               24   
 4      5      F  24.3           1534              946              118   

 Calcium_Actual  Iron_Actual  Energy_DRI  VitaminA_DRI  VitaminC_DRI  \
 0             827           22        1604           700            65   
 1             900           12        2011           700            65   
 2             707            7        2242           700            75   
 3             560           11        1912           700            75   
 4             851           12        1895           700            65   

 Calcium_DRI  Iron_DRI  
 0         1300        15  
 1         1300        15  
 2         1000         8  
 3         1000        18  
 4         1300        15
```

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482722/how-to-print-dataframe-on-single-line

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code in the beginning, please refer [pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```